# I cannot drag drop widgets in Android Studio Layout Editor, I have selected blank activity but there is no app background (frame) in workspace

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout-editor

I have installed all sdk and correctly installed but I have tried multiple times but I cannot fine frame of app where I can insert tool,widgets, button, etc. (Cannot add anything on workspace)

My Android studio window image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8AWJ5JO_e0xVV9KVEE0TUpMYWc/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I think your project was running. Try after it completes

Comment: Please add your images using the editor upload facility, so they go to imgur.com and can be added inline into the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select devices，sdk and theme，like this
image： https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7VdJKtF9NwGNVFKeE5zZ2pxVHM

Comment: Please add your images using the editor upload facility, so they go to imgur.com and can be added inline into the post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've gotten rid of the Component Tree.

Try go to the Text-tab and paste

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

or whatever root layout you need...